# Set variable for a JS function

Tags: javascript

So basically I have a JS function which looks like:

```
var myFunc = function () {
  var settings = {/*my default settings */};  
  function otherFunc(arg){
    /*do stuff*/
  }
  otherFunc(settings);
  return {settings:settings};
}()
```

Now, using the console I can call `myFunc.settings` and it will perfectly output these, however I want to user to overwrite the default settings such as:

```
<script src="myfunc.js"></script>
<script>myFunc.settings = {/*overwrite some settings*/};</script>
```

Now `myFunc.settings` are the new settings, yet the function still uses the 'old' settings. Any clue how I would go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would look into creating an object with mutators/getters.

Comment: what do you mean by "the function still uses the old setting"?

Comment: the myFunc is actually not a function, it's the return value of your anonymous function.

Comment: @grape_mao When the function is called, it uses the default settings and not the settings that has been set afterwards

Comment: because like I said, your myFunc is the return value of that function. You change a value of the return value, of course the function who finished execution won't see it. Have a look at Kyle Weller's answer, he defines a constructor, you can then create new object with it.

Comment: @grape_mao yep, got it! Thanks. Logical, of course... Trying Rob's 2nd alternative now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it a property (and not local) with `this`:

```
function MyFunc () {
  this.settings = {/*my default settings */};  
};
MyFunc.settings = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(MyFunc.settings); // Object {foo: 'bar'}
```

That may expose more than you really want, so you might consider allowing options to be passed when you're constructing whatever you're creating:

```
function MyFunc (options) {
  var defaults = { foo: 'baz' };
  var settings = /* merge defaults and options */;

  /* You probably don't even need to expose settings now. */
};
var instance = new MyFunc({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Comment: Thanks. Using the 2nd alternative now. Works like a charm ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `myFunc` is even a function. It should be an object:

```
var myThing = {
  settings: {/*my default settings */};  
}
```

Then you can call `myThing.settings` to get the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

have an argument where you can pass in settings, if the argument is not supplied, revert to default settings:

```
var myFunc = function (newSettings) {
  var settings = newSettings || {/*my default settings */};  
  //do something
  return {settings:settings};
}
```